# Anything wrong about this code? This is giving me corrupted content

Tags: c#, openxml

```
private static void UpdateFontSettings(WordprocessingDocument content, WordprocessingDocument template)

    {
        if (content != null && content.MainDocumentPart != null && content.MainDocumentPart.FontTablePart != null &&
            template != null && template.MainDocumentPart != null && template.MainDocumentPart.FontTablePart != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<OpenXmlPart> partsToDelete = from idPartPair in content.MainDocumentPart.FontTablePart.Parts
                                                     select idPartPair.OpenXmlPart;

            content.MainDocumentPart.FontTablePart.DeleteParts(partsToDelete);

            StreamReader streamReader = null;
            StreamWriter streamWriter = null;

            try
            {
                streamReader = new StreamReader(template.MainDocumentPart.FontTablePart.GetStream());
                streamWriter = new StreamWriter(content.MainDocumentPart.FontTablePart.GetStream(FileMode.Create));
            }
            catch
            {
                if (streamReader != null)
                {
                    streamReader.Close();
                }

                throw;
            }

            using (streamWriter)
            {
                streamWriter.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            }

            if (streamReader != null)
            {
                streamReader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do the exception happen?

Comment: If it is giving you corrupted content, then __yes__ there is something wrong. You should say what is going wrong, why you think that is wrong and when you think it should be doing.

Comment: Also you may want the using(streamWriter) part in the try..catch block as you could have closed the streamReader

Comment: wow, i can't believe people wasted downvotes on this. he/she is new to SO - cut them some slack and help them learn how to use the site instead of downvotting the crap out of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting your encoding type when you create your `StreamWriter`. I believe it defaults to ANSI for most systems, though you might require UTF8 or something else.